# Scheduled Event Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a scheduled event in my sql that deletes the user who are not verified within 24 hours. Whenever a new user registers, his registration  date and time are stored in column of my db named as 'created'. There is another column that stores user verification status 0 or 1,that column is name 'activation_status'. Now i want proper my sql event that will delete the user if his activation status is zero and more than 24 hours have passed. Below is my sql event code that i tried:

CREATE EVENT hourly_inactive_cleanup ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR DO DELETE FROM users WHERE created <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOURS) AND activation_status = 0;

Sorry for the bad english.

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: INTERVAL 24 HOURS should be INTERVAL 24 HOUR

Comment: Thanks alot P.Salmon it really worked for me. Your help is really appreciated ☺